# Sync folders with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm having some issues using TortoiseSVN/SVN with working folders and the .SVN folder.

Say I have a structure like the following:

```
trunk/
     src/
     sdk/
     lib/
```

If I wanted to check out  the src folder and sdk folder but NOT the lib folder and I do a checkout on the two folders separately, the .SVN folders will be under both src/ and sdk/.

How, then, would I get the /trunk/ folder itself under source control? If I do a checkout then it will checkout everything including the lib folder, unless I limit the depth, in which case it won't know about any subfolders.

Really what I need is some way to sync folders.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the feature myself, but Subversion supports "sparse directories".

> In our example, we operated only on the root of our working copy, changing its ambient depth value. But we can independently change the ambient depth value of any subdirectory inside the working copy, too. **Careful use of this ability allows us to flesh out only certain portions of the working copy tree, leaving other portions absent altogether** (hence the “sparse” bit of the feature's name). Here's an example of how we might build out a portion of one branch of our family's tree, enable full recursion on another branch, **and keep still other pieces pruned (absent from disk).**

You can read more in the svnbook entry for [Spare Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)

Comment: Yeah, that works for when you do a clean checkout, although it doesn't quite help those of us wanting to avoid checking out 20GB of code ;) Ah well.

Comment: It does help avoid that - see my answer below.

Comment: @Jordan 20GB? How did that make it into SVN to begin with?

Answer (score 7):

1. Use TortoiseSVN to checkout the parent directory
2. Select "Fully Recursive" depth
3. Click "Choose Items" and deselect the folders you don't want checked out
4. Click OK.

If you already have the parent directory checked out and you want to change the subset of folders that you have checked out, right click your parent folder and select "TortoiseSVN | Update to Revision...". In this window you can select "Choose Items" and deselect the folders you don't want in your working copy any more.

Comment: Did not know about this. Must be using sparse directories under the hood?

Comment: That's exactly how it works. I included this answer because he was specifically looking for a method using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I know of using Tortoise is to make a blank directory of the same name and then right click on it and choose "Unversion and add to ignore list" from the tortoise svn list item this will make any subsequent updates ignore this folder. I often do it with the compiled code... its easiest to pull it all in then add the folders you don't want to the ignore list then them out.

Comment: But I don't want to permanently ignore the folder, just for this checkout. Also, what do I do if I have already checked the code out? Is there any way to do it without a clean checkout? Surely there should be a way to add another/parent folder to the working copy?

Comment: according to their website you should be able to un-add something to the ignore list. But it seems to have some issues on some systems, it works on 3/4 of my machines. As for adding a parent there is no way to do that without checking out a clean copy. I tried encapsulating it but it kept complaining that the directory I was trying to use already held a working copy

Comment: though if you only want to do it the one time you can choose "Tortoise SVN" -> "Update to revision" then use the choose items button to de-select the ones you don't want.

Comment: make sure you un-tick the make depth sticky though otherwise next time you update it will not come back.

Comment: actually that answers your original question quite nicely, just checkout a clean copy (or update to revision) and use the choose items button to only get the ones you need then use the update to revision button to re-include the ignored folder later (or it will just turn up on the next update if you did not make it sticky.)

Comment: Also judging by the status message I am getting I think it uses the "Sparse Directories" that crashmstr was referring to.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the same thing as sparce directories I guess. Thanks. It looks like I should do a checkout/update on the parent directory but set the depth to "immediate" and then do an update on the folders I want and set depth to be infinity. Kind of a pain in the ass, but I guess that's the solution.

Comment: Jordan, You should be able to do that in one step. Checkout the parent directory, and in the TortoiseSVN Checkout window choose "Fully Recursive" depth and then click "Choose Items" and deselect the folders that you don't want checked out or updated.

Answer (score 0):

Add lib directory to ignore list: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html